# React Native - How to remove unnecessary component react native for reducing the size?

Tags: android, react-native

I wonder why `facebook` has an app with 2MB size and when I bundling `Welcome to react native` or creating a RN project using `react-native init {myAppName}` the size itself growup to 7MB,

So I just assume Facebook deleting all unnecessary [component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis#docsNav) itself (like `Picker`, `ActivityIndicator`, and so on)

That's why I want to know if there's a way to removing all unnecessary component from `node_modules` or from `Installed Library`?

Comment: What app is 2MB?

Comment: [Facebook lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.lite)? I have read [this article](https://code.fb.com/android/how-we-built-facebook-lite-for-every-android-phone-and-network/) but still I'm amaze with the size itself, and wonder how to do, even I used native code (android studio) the app itself take 3MB for `hello world` app

Comment: Are you sure it's built with React Native?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I really want to reduce my apk size, because I have a simple app with *__only one screen__* and the size itself is 12MB with (`React Native`, `React Native File System`, `Realm, React Native Modal Dropdown`) that i think no one want to download the simple app cost 12MB to downloaded

Comment: it is also my issue, is there a ways to reduce app size